# ABNewPersonViewController using contact framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode9

```
- (void)addContact {
    // Creating new entry
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();

    NSString *phone = self.data.phone;
    NSString *cellphone = self.data.cellPhone;
    NSString *fax = self.data.fax;
    NSString *email = self.data.email;
    NSString *firstName = self.data.firstName;
    NSString *lastName = self.data.lastName;

    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(firstName) , nil);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(lastName), nil);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonJobTitleProperty, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(title), nil);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonDepartmentProperty, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(dept), nil);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonOrganizationProperty, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(org), nil);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonNoteProperty, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(unit), nil);

    // Adding phone numbers
    ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(cellphone), (CFStringRef)@"iPhone", NULL);
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(phone), (CFStringRef)@"Work", NULL);
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(fax), (CFStringRef)@"Fax", NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumberMultiValue, nil);
    CFRelease(phoneNumberMultiValue);

    // Adding emails
    ABMutableMultiValueRef emailMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(emailMultiValue, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(email), (CFStringRef)@"Work", NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty, emailMultiValue, nil);
    CFRelease(emailMultiValue);

    // Adding person to the address book
    ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, person, nil);
    CFRelease(addressBook);

    ABNewPersonViewController *c = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
    [c setNewPersonViewDelegate:self];
    [c setDisplayedPerson:person];
    CFRelease(person);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:YES];
}
```

what is the similar code using contacts framework? How to load detail from person (ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();) into *contact (CNMutableContact *contact = [CNMutableContact new];)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using [ContactsUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contactsui) framework rather than the old AddressBookUI framework. So, don't use `ABNewPersonViewController`, but instead use `CNContactViewController`:

```
@import ContactsUI;

@interface ViewController () <CNContactViewControllerDelegate>
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)didTapButton:(id)sender {
    CNMutableContact *contact = [[CNMutableContact alloc] init];
    [contact setGivenName:@"John"];
    [contact setFamilyName:@"Doe"];
    ...

    CNContactViewController *controller = [CNContactViewController viewControllerForNewContact:contact];
    controller.delegate = self;

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    nav.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:true completion: nil];
}

- (void)contactViewController:(CNContactViewController *)viewController didCompleteWithContact:(CNContact *)contact {
    [viewController.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Nowadays, use Contacts and ContactsUI frameworks rather than the deprecated AddressBook and AddresssBookUI frameworks.

Comment: Is [self presentViewController:nav animated:true completion: nil]; will have Done and Cancel option ?   Is there any way I can copy all data from person object into contact  object of how can I load data into contact object for above code?

Comment: controller.delegate = self;   returns error Assigning to 'id<CNContactViewControllerDelegate> _Nullable' from incompatible type 'QuickContactsViewController *const __strong'

Comment: Now it display the data but It doesn't display cancel and Done button .

Comment: i have added to @interface QuickContactsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate, ABPersonViewControllerDelegate,
    ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate, ABUnknownPersonViewControllerDelegate, CNContactViewControllerDelegate >  but same error

Comment: I would like to keep  both so i can support IOS 7 and IOS 10.  Looks like cancel and done button display but its transparent. If i click on top right and top left the page close successfully.

Comment: I am planning to put the check for iOS > 9 used used new method else used method which seems working but on iOS 11 the save contact doesn’t have cancel and done Butt it. Button seems there but looks like it’s transferent because if I click on  top left corner it seems working but buttons are not visible.  right

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController  <CNContactViewControllerDelegate>
I'm getting error Class 'ViewController' defined without specifying a base class

Comment: `@interface ViewController: UIViewController <CNContactViewControllerDelegate>`. In my example above, I assumed you had already declared the `@interface` for the `ViewController`, so I just declared a private class "extension", but both techniques work.

Comment: Pop up header navigation bar , cancel and Done button are white and cannot see the buttons.